# Script ajax publica pero no obtiene

Tags: php, ajax

Tengo un script que publica los datos de unos input, pero si cambio *POST* por *GET* no me obtiene los datos de esa base de datos, incluso si lo dejo como *POST* y en el php pues está las instrucciones para que obtenga datos de la base de datos ¿Cómo puedo solucionarlo?

Este es el código del lado del cliente:

```
bt.onclick = function() {

    var parameters = {
        'user': user.value,
        'password': password.value
    }

}

$.ajax({
    data:parameters,
    url: 'mostrar.php',
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(mensaje) {
        alert(mensaje);
    }
});
```

Del lado del servidor:

```
<?php 

$user = $_POST['user'];
$password = $_POST['password'];


$result = mysqli_query(db, "SELECT * FROM $base WHERE user = $user AND password = $password");

while($view = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "OK";
}

?>
```

Comment: Esto es problema del servidor, podrías poner el código del servidor

Comment: Si cambias en tu **AJAX** el parámetro `type: 'POST'` por el método `GET`, entonces en tu archivo **mostrar.php** debes cambiar todo tus `$_POST` por `$_GET`.

Comment: @christian Ya subí el archivo php

Comment: @Diablo Sigue sin funcionar

Comment: Si haces un `var_dump($_POST);` o `$_GET` si usas dicho método que te muestra en pantalla **(mostrar.php)**? Prueba tambien cambiar `success: function(mensaje) {` por `success: function(parameters) {`

Comment: ¿También sería conveniente que completaras en tu pregunta el código `AJAX`, donde creas las variables `parameters` o `mensaje`?

Comment: @Diablo Ya lo agregué, el mensaje es el echo de php.

Comment: Si cambias `echo "ok"`; por `var_dump($_POST);` o según el método que has puesto que te muestra en pantalla?

Comment: Si en tu ```while``` solo tienes un ```echo "ok"``` mejor quitado y si yenes datos añádelo aun array y luego devuelve los  pero si no vas a retornar datos quita el ```while``` y solo deja el ```echo``` o muestra lo si la consulta es satisfactoria. Además haz el ```var_dump()``` que te diecen

Comment: Muchas gracias, ya lo solucioné, estaba poniendo FORM en vez de FROM en la consulta.